# Relating entities in ER diagram

Tags: database-design, erd

I need to draw an ER diagram which has 3 entities: To-do list, Event and Contacts. These entities are not related to each other and I'm thinking of connecting them using a User entity. Is it okay if the User entity do not have any attribute? How should I convert it into relational table then? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: _How_ do you want to relate them? How many to-dos, events and contacts should any given user have? Are they all required (e.g. can a user be without a contact)?

Comment: Also, can they be shared (e.g. can the same event belong to more than one user)?

Answer (score 0):

A user table would have at least the following fields: ID (primary key), user's full name, user login name, hashed password, email address.....

In the other tables, you would need to add the user ID field to act as a foreign key. So, for example, if you wanted to get a list of to-do items for Becky, you would write

```
select todoitems.name, todoitems.targetdate
from todoitems inner join users on todoitems.user = users.id
where users.username = 'Becky'
and todoitems.done = 0 /* or false */
order by todoitems.targetdate
```

Comment: But it's a single user program, do I still need the user table?

Comment: If it's a single user program, then you don't need the user table - but also there would be no reason to join the other tables. If you wanted to join the todolist and contacts table, then presumably it would be on the basis of having a contact foreign key in the todolist table. Otherwise I can't see any connection between them.